# Does Java support 384 kHz sound sample rate?

Tags: java, audio, sample

I want to use 384 kHz sample rate audio data but when I put this code:

```
final static AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(384000, 8, 2, true, true);
```

It returns an error that this type of data is not supported, although my sound card does support it. I can use up to 200 kHz of sample rate, the bigger numbers don't work. Can I use a higher sample rate by any method, or Java just doesn't support bigger sample rates?

Comment: Are you recording from a microphone? I don't think most normal microphones can record audio at such a high frequency, so I doubt how useful it is to try this.